# ggplot visualize confidence interval of single values (accuracy rates)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, confidence-interval

I would love it if anyone could show me how i can plot not just the accuracy of each classifier, but also the confidence interval (AccuracyLower, AccuracyUpper). Whenever I use ggplot the plot just visualizes the Accuracy, and not the other values. My dataframe looks as follows:

```
compmods <- data.frame(Model = c("SVM", "XGB", "Random forest","Neural net"), Accuracy = c(0.7324477,0.7460202,0.7634408,0.7420827), AccuracyLower = c(0.7297001,0.7433180,0.7608018,0.7393670), AccuracyUpper = c(0.7351819,0.7487083,0.7660646,0.7447845)) 
#this does not produce the desired plot: 
compmods %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Model, y = Accuracy)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_point(aes(Model, AccuracyLower), shape = 20) +
  geom_point(aes(Model, AccuracyUpper))+
  geom_point() +
  ylim(0, 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.695628, 
             color = "Red") +
  labs(title = "Average classifier accuracy compared to no information rate")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for:

```
compmods %>% 
ggplot(aes(Model)) + 
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = AccuracyLower, ymax = AccuracyUpper)) + 
geom_point(aes(y = Accuracy), color = "red", size = 5)
```

[image]

As side note your plot is also working just fine - it plots all points but they are extremely close so they overlap (if the scale is from 0 to 1)